# ASP.Net How to call an Unknown (Dynamic) WSDL Webservice and parse it's result?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, dynamic, wsdl

will appreciate any pointers here. This scenario may sound a bit weird:
I am trying to write a program that consume webservices that user define, and that my program do not know in advance.

For example, my program allow users to set/define all the webservices that they have in their network, into my database.
My program will then show a list of all the webservices that users have defined, and with a click, my program will call THAT webservice (with the parameters that use can key in) and then my program will show the result (string).

Problem is that at design time, I have no idea what are the webservices and the parameters and response. So, I need to dynamically create some sort of a stub that can consume these webservices without having to Add-Reference into my project in advance.

Will appreciate any pointers here.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're trying to build your own [SOAP_UI](http://www.soapui.org/About-SoapUI/what-is-soapui.html) here :) (excellent tool for testing purpose on Webservices) , correct ?

I guess you'd want to play [with wsdl.exe](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12760/Reverse-Engineering-Through-WSDL-EXE).

Comment: Hi, although it sounds familiar, it is not quite. Unlike SOAP_UI that is using those webservices for testing purposes; I'm trying to "consolidate" a wide range of webservices available. Instead of clients calling every services directly, they will invoke my program function with a "serviceID" and basing on the "serviceID", my program will call the appropriate webservice and return the result in a "specific" (universal) format.  Basically, I'm trying to hide all the webservices behind a function.

Any pointers to the right direction will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Ok, so basically you would act like a proxy for those clients. Do you have any processing needed on the responses you will get from the webservices, before forwarding them to your clients ?

If not, maybe you could have a look at IIS proxying (thinking about ARR here, I'm going to read more about that too see if that could fit your needs).

Comment: Yanks so much Melvin for your help! Yes, I will need to massage the response so that my function will return a "unified" formats instead of all the different formats currently. I still have not made any progress on this one. Thanks so much again!